# Erro em código do VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde. Estou com um problema um tanto tolo, mas que não consigo sair. Gerei o código abaixo para que o VBA analise todas as células de um determinado intervalo e, toda vez que ele encontrar uma célula vazia ou com um traço (-), então vai substituir pelo valor zero. Nas linhas o código percorre bem, porém, ele fica preso na primeira coluna (não executa a varredura nas colunas seguintes).

```
Sub alterar()

Dim linha As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Sheets("Tabela").Activate
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 100)).UnMerge
linha = 1
col = 1
Do Until Cells(1, col) <= 5
        Do Until linha = 40
            Cells(linha, col).Select
            If Cells(linha, col).Value = "-" Then
                Cells(linha, col).Value = 0
            End If
        linha = linha + 1
       
        Loop
col = col + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: O que você pretende com `Do Until Cells(1, col) <= 5`? Você quer que o Excel pare de iterar quando encontrar uma coluna cuja primeira célula tenha um valor menor ou igual a 5?

Comment: Correto. Eu preciso que ele pare quando atingir uma quantidade determinada de colunas e linhas

Comment: Você falou "correto" e disse uma coisa diferente do que eu perguntei... Se você quer analisar só 5 colunas, deveria ser `Do While col <= 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que da para fazer de uma maneira mais simples, expliquei os passos no código:

```
Sub alterar()
Dim linha, col As Integer
Dim ref As Range
linha = 0
col = 0
Set ref = Sheets("Planilha1").Range("A1") 'tornar a primeira celula como referencia'

'supondo que sua tabela tem 15 linhas e 7 colunas'

novo_count: 'marcador de recomeço (proximo loop explicado)'
While linha < 15 'limitador de loop pelo número de linhas'
    If ref.Offset(linha, col) = "" Or ref.Offset(linha, col) = "-" Then 'regras do IF'
        ref.Offset(linha, col).Value = 0 'adiciona zero de acordo com as regras'
    End If
    linha = linha + 1 'vai para linha seguinte na mesma coluna'
Wend

While col < 6 'loop do número de colunas da tabela menos 1'
If linha = 15 Then 'check tiver chegado na ultima linha'
    col = 1 + col 'vai para coluna seguinte'
    linha = 0 'zera a contagem de linha'
    GoTo novo_count 'volta do inicio com a col+1(seguinte) e recomeça contagem de linha'
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Se não for obrigado a utilização de VBA, há a função localizar e substituir na Página Inicial